# Generalization of Lévy's theorem on planar Brownian motions

Tags: cv.complex-variables, stochastic-calculus

Recall Lévy's theorem: If $f(z)$ is an analytic function
and $Z_t$ is complex Brownian motion then $f(Z_t)$ is (up to a change of time) a complex Brownian motion as well.

Does the same generalize to the situation in many variables? Can you even prove that a polynomial of several independent complex Brownian motions is a time re-scaled Brownian motion?

Answer (score 2):

In order $f(Z_t)$ be a Brownian motion, $f$ needs to be a conformal mapping. But there are no conformal mappings in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \geqslant 3$) other than translations, rotations, dilations, inversions and compositions of these.

Comment: Hi Mateusz, I am interested in $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a domain for the generalized $f$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$. Trivially, $B^1_t + B^2_t$, the sum of two independent complex Brownian motions, satisfies our property, so some polynomials, i.e. $f(z,w)=z+w$ in this case, do work.

Comment: Complex structure plays no role here: the only condition is that there is a function $\phi$ such that $\Delta (u \circ f)(x) = \phi(f(x)) (\Delta u)(f(x))$ for all $u$ ($\phi$ describes the corresponding time-change). But now I see that your $f$ maps $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a space $\mathbb{R}^m$ of a lower dimension. I bet that such an $f$ must be an (appropriate) affine map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ composed with a conformal map on $\mathbb{R}^m$, but I do not have a reference.